# Joining cell content in column B into a single cell if column A has the same value

Tags: google-sheets

I have:

```
 Column A     Column B
 John         1 
 John         11
 John         3
 John         6
 Ted          5
 Bob          2
 Bob          1
```

I need:

```
Column A     Column B
John         1,11,3,6
Ted          5
Bob          2,1
```

Help, please! Thank you, kind strangers :)

I've tried `=IF(A1<>A2,B2,B1&","&B2)` - it works for only 2 similar cells at a time (e.g. Bob) but won't work for varying occurrences of the same name (e.g. John 4 occurrences, then Ted 1 occurrence, then Bob 2 occurrences).

I have 5,000 lines of this so it has to easily scale.

Answer (score 1):

paste in D1:

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

paste in E1 and drag down:

```
=JOIN(", ", QUERY({A:B}, "select Col2 where Col1='"&D1&"'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: sometimes google sheets is so much slicker than Excel :)